# WSO2-APIM/IS How to configure repository\conf\identity\identity-providers\default.xml

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have created a custom federated authenticator in WSO2-APIM/IS and have enable Just-In-Time Provisioning.

Since in API Manager when an application is created a corresponding service provider will be created as well. I want to have all service provider be using my custom authenticator as default which, I think, can be done by editing the file **repository\conf\identity\identity-providers\default.xml**

However I can not find the information in the documentation on the format of this file which I need to configure my custom federated authenticator and enable JIT Provisioning. Can anyone please guide me to the configuration detail of this file.

Below is the default **repository\conf\identity\identity-providers\default.xml**

```
<IdentityProvider>
    <IdentityProviderName>default</IdentityProviderName>
    <DisplayName>default</DisplayName>
    <IdentityProviderDescription></IdentityProviderDescription>
    <Alias></Alias>
    <IsPrimary></IsPrimary>
    <IsFederationHub></IsFederationHub>
    <HomeRealmId></HomeRealmId>
    <ProvisioningRole></ProvisioningRole>
    <FederatedAuthenticatorConfigs></FederatedAuthenticatorConfigs>
    <DefaultAuthenticatorConfig>
    </DefaultAuthenticatorConfig>
    <ProvisioningConnectorConfigs>
        <!--<ProvisioningConnectorConfig>
            <ProvisioningProperties>
            </ProvisioningProperties>
        </ProvisioningConnectorConfig>-->
    </ProvisioningConnectorConfigs>
    <!--<DefaultProvisioningConnectorConfig></DefaultProvisioningConnectorConfig>-->
    <ClaimConfig></ClaimConfig>
    <Certificate></Certificate>
    <PermissionAndRoleConfig></PermissionAndRoleConfig>
    <JustInTimeProvisioningConfig></JustInTimeProvisioningConfig>
</IdentityProvider>
```

Thank you very much in advanced.

Comment: Check if https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Adding+a+Service+Provider+and+Identity+Provider+Using+Configuration+Files this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the code [here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/blob/v5.0.7/components/application-mgt/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/application/common/model/JustInTimeProvisioningConfig.java#L50-L59), It should be in the following format.

```
<JustInTimeProvisioningConfig>
    <UserStoreClaimUri></UserStoreClaimUri>
    <ProvisioningUserStore>PRIMARY</ProvisioningUserStore>
    <IsProvisioningEnabled>true</ProvisioningEnabled>
</JustInTimeProvisioningConfig>
```

Change the `ProvisioningUserStore` to reflect yours.